# kable could not find function error with Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval causing execution to halt

Tags: knitr, kable

Trying to knit and resulting in this error:

processing file: Project-Template.rmd

Quitting from lines 68-70 (Project-Template.rmd)
Error in kable(round(describe(LoanDefaults[, 2]), 3)) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped",  :
could not find function "%>%"
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Trying to successfully knit (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aywnn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hey welcome to SO. It is good practice to paste the code that produces the error to your question.